# Dataframe replace string with a word and set other rows as NULL using Python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in python, want to replace Fri as this friday and the rest of the rows in that colume as NULL
[image]

Use this code will replace all the rows with this friday, which is not what i want

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
friday = today + datetime.timedelta( (4-today.weekday()) % 7 )
this_firday = friday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

df['date3'] = df.loc[(df['date'] == 'Fri'), 'date'] = this_firday 
df
```

my expected result is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try via `map()`:

```
df['date']=df['date'].map({'Fri':this_firday})
```

OR

via `loc`:

```
df.loc[(df['date'] == 'Fri'), 'date'] = this_firday
df.loc[(df['date'] != 'Fri'),'date']=float('NaN')
```

OR

you can also use `np.where()`:

```
#import numpy as np
df['date']=np.where((df['date'] == 'Fri'),this_firday,np.nan)
```